# Cannot start Hyperledger Fabric as part of Hyperledger Composer local install (even though I've installed everything needed)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I followed all the steps given in https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/development-tools.html
I still am unable to start Hyperledger Fabric. The response I get is as follows:
USF-Wifi-224-54-26:fabric-tools yaasshrao$     ./createPeerAdminCard.sh
Development only script for Hyperledger Fabric control
Running 'createPeerAdminCard.sh'
FABRIC_VERSION is unset, assuming hlfv1
FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT is unset, assuming 15 (seconds)

Need to have composer-cli installed at v0.15 or greater

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you post 1) OS and version 2) docker version `docker -v` 3) did you previously have a Fabric environment running?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure don't use 'sudo npm' when you install npm component. I had to reinstall node to successfully run in my desktop.